# Where to set stripe API key in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I currently have this in every controller action that needs it (quite a few):

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_stripe_test_key]
```

Where is the best place to put this code? The options that come to mind are:

- Leave it where it is in each of the controller actions that need it
- Place it in a `before_action`, and run that before the controller actions that need it
- Place it in a application helper and run it from inside controller actions that need it
- Place it in an `initializer.rb` file and have it run once on the application start

What I currently have isn't DRY, so I figured there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an intializer file inside folder `config/initializers/stripe.rb` and put this key there

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe_secret_key
```

Comment: Does `Rails.application.credentials.stripe_secret_key` do something more fancy than the code I have?

Comment: No I just took from my project and copied it you are doing Env checking and providing key, mine is quick way. Your is fine just copy it to initializers/strip.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the approach mentioned here [Stripe on Ruby on Rails - Creating config/initializers/stripe.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800053/stripe-on-ruby-on-rails-creating-config-initializers-stripe-rb)
You can then have the values in environment variables. This is safer when in production